# Return dynamic list back to MVC post call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of questions that is being sent to my view that is dynamically created. Sometimes there will be 5 questions, sometimes there will be 20 questions. The problem i'm having is passing the values back on the post call.

**data passed to post call**

```
question1:first answer
question2:second answer
question3:third answer
question4:and so on...
question5:and so on...
```

In theory, for my model i could do something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(String question1, ..., String question100) {
   //code
}
```

But that's just nonsensical. What i'm trying to is essentially pass back a list of strings back to the controller. But i'm unsure on how to accomplish that.

**View code (some lines have been removed or renamed)**

```
@using MyWebsite.Models
@model List<QuestionModel>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        int questionNum = 0;
        foreach (QuestionModel question in @Model) {
                questionNum++;    
                <label>@question.Question</label>
                <label class="comment">@question.Comments</label>

                <input data-val="true" data-val-required="This question is required." id="@("question"+questionNum)" name="@("question"+questionNum)" type="text" value=""/>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="@("question"+questionNum)" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>   
        }

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Report" />
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<string> values)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
    <form action="/Sample/Index">

        <input id="values_0" name="values" />
        <input id="values_1" name="values" />

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    </form>
```